# Second order differential

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose I have a function $f = f(x,y,z)$. Then, the first order differential, or the linear approximation is
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz
$$
How do I calculate the next order? Will it be like the Taylor expansion?
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}dx^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}dz^2
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

$$d^2f=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}dx^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}dz^2+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}dxdy+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z}dydz+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial x}dzdx$$

More generally we have

$$d^nf=\left(
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}dx+
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}dy+
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}dz
\right)^nf$$