# Contribution of the arguments to the variation of the function

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following function, with the arguments $r$, $g$ and $d$:

$$f(r,d,g) = \frac{((r - g) * d)}{(1 + g)}$$

I am simulating what happens with the value of $f(r,d,g)$ when $r$, $g$ and $d$ change their values simultaneously. I would like to know the contribution of each argument to the variation of the $f(r,d,g)$ value.

For example, if $r = 0.046$, $g = -0.033$ and $d = 0.655$, the value of $f(r,d,g) = 0.053510858$. If i change the values of the arguments to: $r = 0.047$, $g = -0.032$ and $d = 0.656$, the value of $f(r,d,g) = 0.05353719$. The difference between the two values of $f(r,d,g)$ is $-0.000026332$. I would like to know what is the contribution of the change on the value of each argument to the change in the value of the $f(r,d,g)$. For example, on the value of $-0.000026332$, $x$ is due the change in the value of $r$, $y$ is due the change in the value of $g$ and $w$ is due the change in the value of $d$. Moreover, $x + y + w = -0.000026332$. I would like to know that. And the summation of the contributions would be equal the total variation. I tried to do that using the total differentiation of the $f(r,d,g)$, but the summation of the contributions is not equal the total variation of the function. I noted the summation of the contributions is closer when the variation of the arguments is small. But i have some high variations on the arguments. I would like some help, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for higher order differential: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1516584/144421)

Comment: Thanks @callculus, i got the idea. I did the second order differential but the sum of the individual contributions are very far from the value of the `f(r,d,g) variation.

Comment: I would start with simpler figures: $r=2, g=d=1$

Comment: @callculus: the arguments $dz$, $dx$ and $dy$ are the variations on the arguments $z$, $x$ and $y$, right?

Comment: Yes, they are the (small) changes of x,y and z.

Comment: I assessed the second order differentiation using the value you suggested and put the small changes $dd = 0.1$, $dr = -0.1$ and $dg = 0.1$. The summation of the contributions generated by the second order equation is far from the change in $f(r,d,g)$.

Comment: I gave up. It looks impossible.